# how to convert xacro file to urdf file?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wanna know the command used to convert xacro file to pure urdf file ,

Thanks for ur help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10401/how-to-convert-xacro-file-to-urdf-file?/) by [mhossameldin](https://answers.ros.org/users/758/mhossameldin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dds](https://answers.ros.org/users/57058/dds/) on 2020-07-27**:
Hi. How to do the same with ROS2?

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-05-18**:
In case somebody need it:

ros2 run xacro xacro -o robot.urdf robot.urdf.xacro

robot.urdf  is the output file and robot.urdf.xacro is the file you want to convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Better use the command as intendet:

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder -o model.urdf model.urdf.xacro
```

A proper xml will be generated with a banner saying that the file was auto generated and should not be edited.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr.7th](https://answers.ros.org/users/45840/mr.7th/) on 2019-11-14**:
Could you please provide an example? This is not very clear to me!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py model.xacro > model.urdf
```

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 23

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the most recent versions, xacro.py is deprecated, so something like the following works:

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder model.urdf.xacro > model.urdf
```

---

Originally posted by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) with karma: 148 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For **Noetic**:

rosrun xacro xacro model.xacro > model.urdf

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2